# Расчет времени в течении которого происходит определенное наблюдение

Tags: r

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(time = c('2018-01-03 17:30:00', '2018-01-03 17:45:00', '2018-01-03 18:00:00', '2018-01-03 18:15:00', '2018-01-03 18:30:00', '2018-01-03 18:45:00', '2018-01-04 10:00:00',
                            '2018-01-04 10:15:00', '2018-01-04 10:30:00', '2018-01-04 10:45:00', '2018-01-04 11:00:00', '2018-01-04 11:15:00', '2018-01-04 11:30:00', '2018-01-04 11:45:00', 
                            '2018-01-04 12:00:00', '2018-01-04 12:15:00', '2018-01-04 12:30:00', '2018-01-04 12:45:00', '2018-01-04 13:00:00'   , '2018-01-04 13:15:00'),
                   V1 = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.2, 1.4, 0.6, -0.1, -0.6, -1.4, -2.5, -3, -1.9, -0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 1.1))

data$time <- as.POSIXct(data$time)
```

Есть пример данных в котором присутствует время и некое наблюдение в момент этого времени. Я хочу рассчитать так называемый Half life period, а именно сколько проходит времени начиная с момента превышения порога (скажем плюс/минус 2) до момент когда наблюдение становится равным больше или меньше нуля (при +2  <- время, за которое переменная становится меньше или равна 0, и при -2 <- время, за которое переменная становится больше или равна 0). Из этих расчетов я получу ряд данных времени за которое переменная возвращается к 0 и дальше продолжу анализ этого временного ряда. 
Каким способом я могу провести автоматический расчет по заданным параметрам?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34205515/4827341

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то там идет поиск максимальных и минимальных значений, но в моем случае мне нужно именно начинать расчет с заданного числа (плюс минус 2) и это не обязательно будет максимум или минимум